# Cannot use primary constructor in Scala method: type "does not take parameters"

Tags: scala, constructor

I've got the following definition of Board:

```
package board

import scala.collection.immutable.Vector

class Board private (values: Vector[Vector[Cell]]) {
  private val cells = values

  def updated(i: Int, j: Int)(newValue: Cell): Board =
    this(
      cells.updated(
        i, cells(i).updated(j, newValue)
      )
    )
}
```

where `Cell` is

```
case class Cell(value: Option[Int])
```

Inside `updated` function at line `this(` I've got an error

> board.Board does not take parameters

which seems odd since it definitely does. Why is this happening?

P.S. in reality my class aims to be more useful and contains a public constructor, but the above is a MCVE to get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I called `this` outside of a constructor. I needed to change it to `new Board`:

```
def updated(i: Int, j: Int)(newValue: Cell): Board =
  new Board(
    cells.updated(
      i, cells(i).updated(j, newValue)
    )
  )
```